# Show native datepicker

Tags: html, datepicker

I have couple of input-dates and my boss don't really like them unless you can select a date only with your mouse... I'm having a bit of a hard time convincing him that native is better. any arguments to keep it is also welcome as an acceptable answer.

Of course you can always click the little arrow to select a date with your mouse. But he thinks most of the user will miss this. So i changed the arrow for a calendar icon but what else can i do?

To make this more intuitive, it would be great if I could bring up the native datepicker UI when the user moves the focus to the input. I can tell you that he isn't completely pleased with the look of the picker either.

Is there a method that I can use to trigger the datepicker UI? I know you can send alt+down key to show it, can it be triggered?